# OpsWorks chef deploy custom json to php

Tags: php, ruby, deployment, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I'm trying to pass sensitive app config data to instances when they get deployed, like db connection info.

Heres the custom stack json string

```
{
  "deploy": {
    "development": {
      "app" : {
        "api_key" : "data",
        "api_secret" : "data",
        "gmail_account" : "data",
        "gmail_account_password" : "data"
      },
      "database" : {
        "db_hostname" : "data",
        "db_username" : "data",
        "db_password" : "data",
        "db_database" : "data"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have my repo setup like this

recipes/appsetup.rb

```rb
node[:deploy].each do |application, config|
  template "#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current/config.php" do
    source "config.php.erb"
    mode 0660
    group deploy[:group]

    if platform?("ubuntu")
      owner "www-data"
    elsif platform?("amazon")   
      owner "apache"
    end

    variables(
      :api_key    => (deploy[:app][:api_key] rescue nil),
      :api_secret => (deploy[:app][:api_secret] rescue nil),
      :gmail_account          => (deploy[:app][:gmail_account] rescue nil),
      :gmail_account_password => (deploy[:app][:gmail_account_password] rescue nil),
      :db_hostname => (deploy[:database][:db_hostname] rescue nil),
      :db_username => (deploy[:database][:db_username] rescue nil),
      :db_password => (deploy[:database][:db_password] rescue nil),
      :db_database => (deploy[:database][:db_database] rescue nil)
    )
  end
end
```

and then the php template at
templates/default/config.php.erb

```php
$config = array();
$config['api_key'] = '<%= @api_key%>';
$config['api_secret'] = '<%= @api_secret%>';
$config['gmail_account'] = '<%= @gmail_account%>';
$config['gmail_account_password'] = '<%= @gmail_account_password%>';

$db = array();
$db['default']['hostname'] = '<%= @db_hostname%>';
$db['default']['username'] = '<%= @db_username%>';
$db['default']['password'] = '<%= @db_password%>';
$db['default']['database'] = '<%= @db_database%>';
```

What would I put under Custom Chef Recipes Deploy? I have tried lots of things but I can't seem to get my recipe loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your repo setup appears to be configured to contain a single cookbook. OpsWorks requires your Custom Cookbooks Repository to contain a collection of cookbooks.

Have a look at the official AWS OpsWorks Cookbooks folder structure:
https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks

In your case:

1. Create a new folder inside your repo and give a name that describes the recipes functionality. In this example, we'll call the folder 'php_app_config'.
2. Move your recipes and templates into this folder, resulting in the following paths from the base of your repo:

   - php_app_config/recipes/appsetup.rb
   - php_app_config/templates/default/config.php.erb
3. Commit your changes to your remote repository and instruct your existing OpsWorks instances to download the latest [custom cookbooks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-installingcustom-enable-update.html).
4. In your Layer's Custom Chef Recipes, add the recipe to the Deploy Lifecycle event using the following name: php_app_config::appsetup
5. Deploy your application.

Comment: Wow I knew I was missing something basic, everything worked like a charm! Neat chef, thanks!